# Ordering post with time and points (like reddit) firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I what to create a query for firebase firestore that gives me the "hottest" posts. I want a query like this to work with nodejs:

```
SELECT Title, LOG10(Likes + 1) * 86400 / .301029995663981 + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Submitted) AS Hotness
FROM article
ORDER BY Hotness DESC
```

What is the best way of doing this with firestore?

Credit for this query: [Reddit hotness score](http://restfulmvc.com/reddit-algorithm.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add a field in each `post` document with the value of the calculation.

Each time a post doc is updated, you would update this field [through a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) (i.e. from the back-end). Since Cloud Functions code is executed with admin privileges, you can write a security rule that prevents the user directly updating this field (See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)), and still have the field updated by the Cloud Functions.

To do the calculation, you need the nbr of likes, which you should have and the creation date.

For the creation date, just do do as follows when you create the doc:

```
....collection('posts').add({foo: 'bar', ..., createdOn: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

---

This way, your query is a very simple orderBy query, see the Firestore [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=0#order_and_limit_data).

Comment: So I would have to update this score often, this does not seem very efficient, I'm I wrong?

Comment: You would need to update a doc each time the number of likes change. In the NoSQL world, and especially with Firestore, since you cannot build complex queries based on aggregations or calculations, this is quite a classical approach. Note that in terms of pricing, it will approximately cost one write and one Cloud Function invocation. CF invocations cost $0.40/million and Firestore writes cost $0.18/100K.